# Uncaught ReferenceError: Ionic is not defined

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic, push-notification

Estou tentando realizar um "Android Push Notification" com o [ionic.io](https://apps.ionic.io). Estou travado em um erro que não consigo resolver:

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: Ionic is not defined"

Já tentei de tudo e não consegui resolver.

- O pode gerar esse erro?

**Esse é o código**

```
var push = new Ionic.Push({ // linha do erro
"debug" : true
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defina o serviço nos seguintes lugares:

na linha de comando, adicione a plataforma webclient e o plugin

```
    $ ionic add ionic-platform-web-client
    $ ionic plugin add phonegap-plugin-push --variable SENDER_ID="GCM_PROJECT_NUMBER"
    $ ionic io init
```

na carga da página principal (index.html):

```
    <script src="lib/ionic-service-core/ionic-core.js"></script>
```

//na carga da aplicação (app.js?):

```
    angular.module('App', [ 'ionic', 'ionic.service.core', ...
```

rode a app e verifique na console do Chrome:

```
>Ionic
   Object {DataTypes: Object, IO: Object, ...
```